# Why the program isn't terminating?

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I am making a program that counts the frequency of elements in an array list and then prints the element that has the maximum frequency. But the program isn't printing anything and doesn't terminate either.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestClass {
        static class FastReader
        {
            BufferedReader br;
            StringTokenizer st;

            public FastReader()
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new
                         InputStreamReader(System.in));
            }

            String next()
            {
                while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                    }
                    catch (IOException  e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return st.nextToken();
            }

            int nextInt()
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(next());
            }

            long nextLong()
            {
                return Long.parseLong(next());
            }

            double nextDouble()
            {
                return Double.parseDouble(next());
            }

            String nextLine()
            {
                String str = "";
                try
                {
                    str = br.readLine();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return str;
            }
            void close() {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String sfds[]) throws Exception {
            FastReader s= new FastReader();
            int N = s.nextInt();
            ArrayList<String> comp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
                comp.add(s.next());

            int count = 0;
            String ele="";
            while(comp.size()>0){
                String e = comp.get(0);
                int c = Collections.frequency(comp, e);
                if(c>count){
                    comp.removeAll(Collections.singleton(e));
                    count=c;
                    ele=e;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(ele);
        }


}
```

I am removing all the occurrences of the element that has been counted. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Well for one, your `print(ele)` is outside the `while` loop. I'd suggest you step through your code using the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: It won't terminate most likely because `(c > count)` is never true, so `comp` list is never empty. And since you modify what `count` value is, that's very likely is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with your code snippet:

- you are only removing elements from list if frequency is greater than current count value which is causing while loop to run indefinitely. Remove the elements even if the frequency is not greater than count.

  ```
      while (comp.size() > 0) {
      String e = comp.get(0);
      int c = Collections.frequency(comp, e);
      if (c > count) {
          count = c;
          ele = e;
      }
      comp.removeAll(Collections.singleton(e));
  }
  System.out.print(ele);
  ```

After doing this minor change your code is working perfectly fine. 
**Input:** 8 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 3
**Output:** 1